# How to use Google Sign-In API with swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, gmail-api, google-signin

I am trying to implement the Google Sign In API so that users can authenticate both Gmail and Google Drive in my iOS app. I want to have two Google Sign in buttons (one in the first tutorial and one in the apps settings in case you want to change accounts later), but can not get either one to work. I tried following [these](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift) [three](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) but can't get the sign in buttons to work. Right now clicking the buttons will bring up the sign-in screen, let you login, bring you back to the app, and then nothing else happens (I can't use any of the account info). Here is the code I have:

**App Delegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .red
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .blackOpaque
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white

    // Initialize Google sign-in
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError as Optional)")

    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                                 sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,
                                                 annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

**Table View Controller (the settings screen)**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send")

    // Uncomment to automatically sign in the user.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    // Implement these methods only if the GIDSignInUIDelegate is not a subclass of UIViewController.

    // Stop the UIActivityIndicatorView animation that was started when the user
    // pressed the Sign In button
    func signInWillDispatch(signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {
        //myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    // Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//MARK: - Google Stuff
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        //let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        //let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let email = user.profile.email
        let fullName = user.profile.name

        UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "googleEmail")
        print("signed in \(fullName as Optional) to Google")
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

@IBAction func didTapSignOut(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "googleEmail")
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Swift but check the following video tutorial on  [Adding Google Sign-in to your iOS App - Sign in series #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmnI5c85sf0) and [Sign in series #3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdhvnywOcvo) to see if you have implemented the Google Sign-in properly. You can also check the quickstart of [Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) and [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios) APIs for code implementation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

You must need **Client ID** for Google Sign in.
Make sure that you have a google account to get a **Client ID**.

Let me explain the procedure to get a **Client ID** from google account.

You need to sign into **Google Developers Console** using your Google Account.

**Step 2:**

Create a Simple Swift App using Xcode,if you haven't created yet.

If you have already created an application, choose your application name.Add your App bundle identifier.

If it asks for your country/region.
You should put your country/region and click on Continue button.

**​Step 3:**

​
Select Google service you want to use.

Click on Google Sign-in to select and click on the button to enable Google Sign-in service.

Now the Google Sign in service is enabled for your application.

**Step 4:**

Download GoogleService-info.plist

Now you can download GoogleService-info.plist  file.You will use it later while configuring your Xcode project

**Step 5**

Configure Your Xcode Project

Now, create a new Xcode project:

However,to implement Google Sign-in service,you will need Google Sign-in SDK

[Download Google Sign-in SDK.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk)

Add GoogleService-Info.plist to the root of your Xcode project.
​

I found the best [tutorial in detail by Huntmyideas](https://www.huntmyideas.com/blogs/how-to-integrate-google-signin-sdk-in-ios-application-using-swift)